# Is there a maximum "healthy" size for a part in a Merge Tree?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table with [this schema](https://gist.github.com/fpacifici/a309c69bf00aba0670cb7f5a5a0dc785) on a 3 nodes cluster (3 replicas, one shard) running on Clickhouse 20.7.2. I did not change any merge tree config setting from the default.

As expected parts generated by Clickhouse background merge reach a maximum size of around 150Gb. Which generates partitions with 10-20 parts regularly. This seems expected.

Occasionally I run an OPTIMIZE FINAL on some partitions to remove duplicates. This, as expected, squashes the parts together and generates parts as big as 350Gb.

Is there any specific concern I should watch out for when running parts that are that big?
Also is there a reason for the default max part size generated by background merges to be specifically 150Gb ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any specific concern I should watch out for when running parts that are that big?

No concern.

> Also is there a reason for the default max part size generated
> by background merges to be specifically 150Gb ?

No particular reason. Yandex did not know beforehand what value is good enough and they set 100GB. Later (December 2017) they have decided to increase it gradually to 300GB (or 500GB?) and they did the first try and changed it and they have set 150GB and they got ton of complaints because all systems for all users started merge old parts and became very slow. So they decided never change this param anymore.